# date variables in JOINed SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, date, join

```
$sql = 'SELECT have_show FROM `date` WHERE DATE(`date`.day) = ?';
$this->db->query($sql, array($date));            //works fine
```

This works fine as expected.

```
$sql = 'SELECT actors, visitors, tickets, have_show FROM show
            JOIN `date` ON show.day = `date`.id
            WHERE DATE(`date`.day) = ?';

$this->db->query($sql, array($date));
```

here, with joined statements it gives 0 results.

**db schema**

```
id(AI)     day(INT FK-date.id)    actors(INT)    visitors(INT)  
  1                 2                   3               45               

id(AI)     day(DATE)               have_show(BOOLEAN)
  1       2012-12-06                       0
  2       2012-12-07                       1
```

codeigniter's active records does the same.

Any of you ever suffered from this kind of poblems?

Comment: Post your table schemas.

Comment: Need to see your schema. Looks like you're trying to join a date against an ID?

Comment: I bet there is no `show` row that has the same value in `show.day` as the row returned by `date.day = 1` would have in `date.id`

Comment: show your table `show` and table `date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
     $sql = 'SELECT actors, visitors, tickets, acts FROM `show`
        JOIN `date` ON show.day = date.id
        WHERE DATE(date.day) = ?';

    $this->db->query($sql, array($date));
```

you have mixed between `date.day` and `date.id`.

or maybe u have `show.id` not `show.day` so look what u have in your table and if yes

replace in your sql `show.day` by `show.id`

EDIT:

```
     $sql = 'SELECT s.day s.actors, s.visitors, s.tickets, s.acts d.day FROM `show` s
        JOIN `date` d ON s.day = d.id ';
```

Comment: `day` in show is `FK` to `date.id`, `date.day` is `DATE` field

Comment: can u give exemple of date in show table and date in date table ?

Comment: sorry, i'd written `FK date.day` in the shcema, i've edited. have been  failing at this from last night

Comment: this my best edit . your `where` is no meaning because u are already taking the date in `on` clause , so with your `where` clause it will be two conditions of date

Comment: then how can i query by saying, `where date.day = 2012-12-07`

Comment: then use `LEFT JOIN` instead and put your where clause